# I need to update a record in PHP containg HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a PHP form to update a database record. I don't have a problem with most of the records, but there is one that I need to put html into. If I only enter regular text or single quotes it updates, but if I put double quotes or other HTML it doesn't.

Here is my page

```
<?php

//start session
session_start(); 

$hostname_DuskySportCenter = "localhost";
$database_DuskySportCenter = "test";
$username_DuskySportCenter = "test";
$password_DuskySportCenter = "test";

$con=mysqli_connect($hostname_DuskySportCenter,$username_DuskySportCenter,$password_DuskySportCenter,$database_DuskySportCenter);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//update a record
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE CSINSTOCK SET name=\"{$_POST['name']}\", description=\"{$_POST['description']}\"  WHERE id=9999 ");

//get record set
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `CSINSTOCK` WHERE `id` = '9999' ");


echo  '<form action="monthly-specials-cs-update.php" method="post">';

//table heading row
echo '<table width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">';
  echo  '<tr>';
  echo   '<td>ID</td>';
  echo   '<td>NAME</td>';
  echo   '<td>description</td>';
  echo   '<td>sort</td>';
  echo   '<td>active</td>';
  echo   '<td>sold</td>';
  echo   '<td>message</td>';
  echo   '<td>price</td>';
  echo   '<td>financing</td>';
  echo   '<td>img1</td>';
  echo  '<td>img2</td>';
  echo   '<td>img3</td>';
  echo   '<td>img4</td>';
  echo   '<td>img5</td>';
  echo   '<td>img6</td>';
  echo   '<td>img7</td>';
  echo   '<td>img8</td>';
  echo   '<td>img9</td>';
  echo  '<td>img10</td>';
  echo  '</tr>';

//display data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {


  echo  '<tr>';
  echo   '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="' . $row['name'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><textarea name="description" value="' .  $row['description']. '">' . $row['description'] .'</textarea></td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="sort" value="' . $row['sort'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="active" value="' . $row['active'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="sold" value="' . $row['sold'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="message" value="' . $row['message'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="price" value="' . $row['price'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="financing" value="' . $row['financing'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img1" value="' . $row['img1'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img2" value="' . $row['img2'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img3" value="' . $row['img3'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img4" value="' . $row['img4'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img5" value="' . $row['img5'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img6" value="' . $row['img6'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img7" value="' . $row['img7'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img8" value="' . $row['img8'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img9" value="' . $row['img9'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo   '<td><input type="text" name="img10" value="' . $row['img10'] . '" />&nbsp;</td>';
  echo '</tr>';

  }

//closing tag for table  
echo '</table>';
echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="submit" /></form>';



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You might want to remove the password from your code.

Comment: **Read this, now!** [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Since the password will be in the edit history (unless OP edits it out in the next min or so), it should either be changed on the database, or this question should be deleted (unless a mod can scrub the password from the edit history).

Comment: I think if the OP makes changes within 5 (?) minutes, there's no edit history to be seen. If I'd editted it, then there would definitely have been one, which is why I didn't do it. Of course, that's entirely moot now.

Comment: I can't believe I did that!

Answer (score 1):

Look up `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.
Not using this will create bugs and more importantly, huge security issues. (http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)